# Qual a função para ver a distância de tanque à parede no robocode?

Tags: java, jogos, inteligência-artificial

Estou tentando implementar no sourcecode do robocode (para quem não conhece, segue o link: http://robocode.sourceforge.net/) um meio de fazer o tanque continuar andando e, a partir de certa distância da parede, tentar retornar.

Por enquanto esse é o código que eu tentei, mas não sei como detectar a distância até as paredes:

```
package towerbot;  
import robocode.`*`;  
import java.awt.`*`;  
public class Towerbot extends Robot  
{  
    boolean movingforward;  
    public void run() {  
        setBodyColor(new Color(0,200,0));  
        while(true) {  
            setAhead(50);  
            setAhead(100);  
        }  
    }  
    public void onScannedRobot(ScannedRobotEvent e) {  
    turnGunRight(getHeading() - getGunHeading() + e.getBearing());  
    fire(1);  
    }  
    public void onHitByBullet(HitByBulletEvent e) {  

    }  
    public void onHitWall(HitWallEvent e) {  

    }   
}
```

Comment: Material de estudo por aqui: leia as questões da tag [tag:inteligência-artificial]. Algum outro material útil (em inglês) aqui: https://game-ai.zeef.com De todas as formas, este site não é um fórum. Se não fez ainda, por favor faça o [tour] e leia [ask]. Eu adoro o Robocode, mas a sua pergunta precisa ser mais objetiva. O que vc já tentou fazer? Edite a questão para postar o trecho de código em que você já tem e explicar a forma que tentou atingir o que deseja.

Comment: Se por outro lado a sua dúvida é essencialmente o que está no título (qual função pra detectar a distância? ou como calcular a distância até um alvo?), edite a questão e faça o corpo da pergunta ser condizente com o título (dai eu retiro meu voto para fechar como ampla). :)

Comment: Estou tentando implementar no sourcecode do robocode (para quem não conhece, segue o link: http://robocode.sourceforge.net/) um meio de fazer o tanque continuar andando e, a partir de certa distância da parede, tentar retornar. Como posso implementar isso?

Comment: "Estou tentando implementar..." -> o que vc já fez? Repito: poste o trecho do seu código em que vc já tentou implementar algo nesse sentido, pois vai facilitar pra entendermos exatamente **onde** está a sua dificuldade.

Answer (score 6):

Bom, se a sua necessidade é apenas calcular a distância até as paredes, eis um exemplo de código que faz isso:

```
package towerbot;
import robocode.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Towerbot extends robocode.Robot
{
    boolean movingforward;

    Point2D direcao;  // Vetor normalizado com a direção de movimento do tanque
    Point2D canto;    // Vetor do tanque até o canto mais próximo a que ele se aproxima
    double distancia; // Distância até as paredes

    final double limite = 80; // Limite utilizado para troca de direção

    public void run() {  
        setBodyColor(new Color(0,200,0));  
        while(true) {  
            ahead(5);
            calculaDistancia();

            if(distancia <= limite)
                turnLeft(180);
        }  
    }  

    public void calculaDistancia() {

        // Pega a altura e largura do campo de batalha e posição x,y do tanque
        double h = getBattleFieldHeight(); // Altura
        double w = getBattleFieldWidth();  // Largura
        double x = getX();
        double y = getY();

        // Pega a direção em que o tank se move e a sua posição atual (x, y) no campo de batalha
        double ang = getHeading(); // O ângulo está em graus, variando entre 0 (apontando pra cima) e 359) no sentido horário

        // Calcula os vetor normal de direção do tanque
        double dx = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(ang));
        double dy = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(ang));
        direcao = new Point2D.Double(dx, dy);

        // Calcula o vetor do tanque em direção ao canto mais próximo da direção e sentido que ele segue
        dx = (direcao.getX() > 0) ? w - x : -x;
        dy = (direcao.getY() > 0) ? h - y : -y;
        canto = new Point2D.Double(dx, dy);

        // Calcula os angulos entre o vetor de direcao e os vetores dos os eixos x e y
        double angX = Math.acos(Math.abs(direcao.getX()));
        double angY = Math.acos(Math.abs(direcao.getY()));

        // A distância é o cateto adjascente do menor ângulo
        if(angY < angX)
            distancia = Math.abs(canto.getY() / Math.cos(angY));
        else
            distancia = Math.abs(canto.getX() / Math.cos(angX));
    }   

    public void onPaint(Graphics2D g) {
        // Desenha a linha até a parede em amarelo se maior do que o limite, e em vermelho se menor do que o limite
        if(distancia <= limite)
            g.setColor(java.awt.Color.RED);
        else
            g.setColor(java.awt.Color.YELLOW);
        g.drawLine((int) getX(), (int) getY(), (int) (getX() + (distancia * direcao.getX())), (int) (getY() + (distancia * direcao.getY())));

        // Desenha o valor da distância em branco
        g.setColor(java.awt.Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("Distancia: " + distancia, 10, 10);

        // Desenha as componentes do vetor do canto tracejados em branco
        Stroke pontilhado = new BasicStroke(1, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0, new float[]{10}, 0);
        g.setStroke(pontilhado);
        g.setColor(java.awt.Color.WHITE);
        g.drawLine((int) getX(), (int) getY(), (int) (getX() + canto.getX()), (int) getY()); // Componente em X
        g.drawLine((int) getX(), (int) getY(), (int) getX(), (int) (getY() + canto.getY())); // Componente em Y
     }

    public void onScannedRobot(ScannedRobotEvent e) {  
        //turnGunRight(getHeading() - getGunHeading() + e.getBearing());  
        //fire(1);
    }  

    public void onHitByBullet(HitByBulletEvent e) {  

    }  

    public void onHitWall(HitWallEvent e) {  

    }   
}
```

O resultado é um robô com esse comportamento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Explicando o código:

Basicamente eu uso alguns cálculos geométricos (tentei fazer de forma mais didática) para obter o vetor de direção do movimento do tanque (a partir do ângulo que o Robocode devolve) e então calcular os componentes nos eixos x e y (marcados em branco com linhas pontilhadas) e "projetar" o vetor de direção conforme o lado de ângulo menor (basicamente, a distência é a hipotenusa jogada na fórmula do cosseno).

O "mecanismo de decisão" tá bem simples, e como vc queria: ele inverte o sentido de movimento se a distância se tornar menor do que um limite estabelecido.

> **Observações**:
>
> - Note que os traçados são informações de depuração, desenhadas na chamada do método `onPaint` e que precisa ser habilitado com o botão
>     "*Paint*" na janela de console do seu robô.
> - Há outras formas melhores de fazer o robô evitar paredes. Sugiro ler a documentação, principalmente os exemplos como o
>     [*Wall Smoothing*](http://robowiki.net/wiki/Wall_Smoothing) (e [suas implementações](http://robowiki.net/wiki/Wall_Smoothing/Implementations)).